# How to take input from the user, then if that input is equal to a string, then do something

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game and I want to take input from the user, then store it in a string, and then check if it equals something, then, do something.

So, `if input == string` then do something.
What I have already tried:

```
public class Code : MonoBehaviour
{
    StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder(5, 100);
    public string _code = "START";
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        code.Append(Input.inputString);
        Debug.Log(code);

    }
}
```

This does print the input out, but if I try

```
if (code == _code)
{}
```

it throws the following error

> "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'StringBuilder'
>   and 'String'.

After fixing that, I tried

```
public class Code : MonoBehaviour
{
    StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder(5, 100);
    public string _code = "start".ToLower();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        code.Append(Input.inputString);
        Debug.Log(code);

        if (code.ToString().ToLower() == _code)
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct!" + code);
        }

    }
}
```

But it's not printing "Correct! start", and only start.
Sorry, complete noob here.

Comment: Are you sure that `Input.inputString` is "start"? Also, why are you convoluting the code so much? why are you using a StringBuilder instead of comparing directly `Input.inputString`?

Comment: @Gusman Yes, I typed "start", and it logged "start", so, yeah, pretty sure it's "start". And if I use Input.inputString instead of the StringBuilder, then it outputs "s", then "t" and so on.

Comment: Debug your project and check the content of "code", I think you will see something like "ssssstttttaaarrrrrtttt" or "s     t    a  r   t". If that's the case it's because you are appending the content of "inputString" on each frame and you must filter it to append only the text when a new key is pressed.

Comment: It's "start"...

Comment: If it is "start" it must pass the "if", so no, it's not "start". Debug it again and step over the code to verify why it fails.

Comment: Found it. Somehow _code became "START". Changed code.ToString().ToLower to .ToUpper().That fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

StringBuilder in C# is literally a string builder and not string itself. You have to get the string from it by using `ToString()`.

If you curious about why Log of `code` prints well, It seems like `Debug.Log(x)` call `x.ToString()` internally.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder

```
if (code.ToString() == _code)
{
   ///any code you want
}
```